# How to use async attribute in script tag in haml?

Tags: html, haml

How to add attributes like `async` or `defer` in script tag in Haml? I tried to put it on a same line as href, but it does not work.

```
 %a.twitter-share-button{href: "https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw", data: { url: "http://example.net", show: { count: "false" } } } Tweet
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
%script{async: true, await: true, src: "hogehoge.com/test.js"}
```

I found that I could put those attributes to script tag with this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
%script{async: 'async', src: 'hogehoge.com/test.js', type: 'application/javascript'}
```